# Is there a way to automate Windows Acrobat or Acrobat Reader to print a PDF to printer output file?

Tags: acrobat

My goal is to automate preprocessing shipping labels that are presented in PDF format to convert them to Zebra ZPL.

The newer Zebra printers can be setup to accept a raw PDF and output the label. But it takes about 2.5 seconds to process and start printing. Whereas if I send ZPL as generated by the ZDesigner printer driver it starts to print almost immediately. This will increase the automated labeling significantly.

I have found non-Adobe references to the command line options for Acrobat Reader which allow me to silently print to a printer driver.

```
/T <filename> <printername> <drivername> <portname>

<filename> specifies the path and filename of the PDF file to print.
<printername> specifies the name of the printer to print to. If the printer name contains spaces, you must enclose it in double quotes.
<drivername> specifies the name of the printer driver to use. If this parameter is omitted, the default printer driver is used.
<portname> specifies the name of the port to use when printing. If this parameter is omitted, the default port is used.
```

If I try these command lines, assuming a path to Acrobat Reader I get a printed label. It does not prompt for a file name. If I change the driver's port setting to FILE: it does, as expected. It seems the `portname` option is not supported or I am using it incorrectly.

```
C:\>Acrobat.exe /t "shipping label.pdf" "ZDesigner ZE521 RH-300dpi ZPL" "" "FILE:"

C:\>Acrobat.exe /t "shipping label.pdf" "ZDesigner ZE521 RH-300dpi ZPL" "ZDesigner ZE521 RH-300dpi ZPL" "FILE:"

C:\>Acrobat.exe /t "shipping label.pdf" "ZDesigner ZE521 RH-300dpi ZPL" "ZDesigner ZE521 RH-300dpi ZPL" "FILE:TEST.ZPL"

C:\>Acrobat.exe /t "shipping label.pdf" "ZDesigner ZE521 RH-300dpi ZPL" "ZDesigner ZE521 RH-300dpi ZPL" "LPT1:"
```

Is there something I'm missing? It's possible that the references I've found to the command line options are outdated and I need to do something else.

Comment: @KJ - I have no trouble printing to the printer. I was trying to convert the customer supplied PDF to ZPL for later printing.

Comment: @KJ I'm sure the values I gave were correct. I do think trying to print to FILE: via the command line though is crippled. At this point I don't think my question has a positive answer.

The workaround I am going with is to do this via an application that launches an instance of Acrobat to print to the print driver as described in the question. The same application will monitor a local port that the printer driver port is set to such as 127.0.0.1:9100. My application will capture that stream and save it to a file or database. Repeat for each required file for the batch.

Answer (score 0):

I  am struggling to see why printer port is your issue the command works perfectly, when you set the port to the hard drive:file.port . So unless there is a com's error it can go to any software firmware or hardware port local LAN or WAN via wireless or 128 cables in parallel such as `\\server\share\file.prn` or c: or v: they are all ports.

[image]
[image]

Print is another word for send a copy, Here we can copy the file to a physical printer but there are many methods all just as fast or as slow as any other. Simplest is `copy filename \\Server Name\\{Printer Share Name}`   (like `COPY out.ps "\\localhost\\Laser Writer"` or if you switched it on in windows see lpr /?) if that's what is local.

[image]
[image]

Much faster is use native fonts as simple text from notepad etc without using PDF
[image]

Comment: Thank you for testing this and providing me a working example.  I've double checked and it doesn't generate a file for me.  While testing I've found that it doesn't like SUBST drives or paths without a drive letter for the source PDF, so I made sure the output file followed the same rules. I do see the provided PDF in the recent files list in Reader.

Comment: It does not work with the three computer I tested, but they are all 64-bit programs and yours is 32-bit. The file option may be broken in the 64-bit version. The Zebra printer does support PDF Direct but ZPL is much faster. As the /t seems to be unofficial and not documented, I may check GhostScript for a supported option.